# When I write a string to an image field in SQL it gets saved in UTF-16 LE encoding and I need it to be UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, blob, sql-server-2016, enterprise, varbinarymax

I have about 1200 databases in SQL 2016 Enterprise in which documents are stored as BLOB's in image fields in the database. I migrated all the documents to our Document Management System and now I want to replace the files in the database with shortcuts to the corresponding files in the DMS. I tried it a few months ago and that went well. Now I run into an issue. When I use this command

```
convert(varbinary(max), <string value of shortcut>)
```

It get's written to the field. When I try to open the shortcut I get an error. If I create the same shortcut from our DMS it is exactly the same except for the encoding. My binary = UTF-16 little endian and the DMS shortcut is encoded in UTF-8. The filesize has also doubled, which is logical since UTF-16 uses two bytes for every character. When I change the encoding in Notepad++ my shortcut works.

I need my blob to be encoded in UTF-8. That is possible, I can upload a shortcut to the system that the database uses and then it's stored correctly. I can't change the collation of the table or field because this is a vendor database. It's a pretty old-fashioned system. Who uses Blob's in the first place and if you do, why image and not varbinary?

I'm not much of a programmer so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried updating the database to the latest client version (not SQL just the application). That didn't change anything.
I tried nvarchar but that doesn't work on image fields.

Comment: I tried some more stuff:
Converting to Nvarchar and then to Varbinary
Result: the bytesize is extremely small but the varbinary determines the encoding to UTF-16 LE
Converting to Varbinary and then to Nvarchar
Result: The image field still doesn't accpet Nvarchar input
Added a collation COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8
Result: error message, this is only available in SQL 2019. That could be a last resort.

Comment: Chat GPT also gave me the suggestion to use Nvarchar

Comment: Chat GPT also came up with: convert(varbinary(max),@string,1 )
Result: Error converting data type nvarchar to varbinary.

Comment: I fixed this issue with a workaround. I installed a SQL Express Server 2019 and linked it to the other SQL instance. Then I made a table with the same fieldtype image and used this syntax:  `convert(varchar(max), <string>  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8)` 
Then I scripted the image field value from the SQL 2019 table imagefield to the other database and it worked!